# Encoding issues on OpenAI predictions after fine-tuning

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, openai-api, gpt-3

I'm following [this OpenAI tutorial](https://beta.openai.com/docs/guides/fine-tuning/create-a-fine-tuned-model) about fine-tuning.

I already generated the dataset with the openai tool. The problem is that the outputs encoding (inference result) is mixing UTF-8 with non UTF-8 characters.

The generated model looks like this:

```
{"prompt":"Usuario: Quién eres\\nAsistente:","completion":" Soy un Asistente\n"}
{"prompt":"Usuario: Qué puedes hacer\\nAsistente:","completion":" Ayudarte con cualquier gestión o ofrecerte información sobre tu cuenta\n"}
```

For instance, if I ask "¿Cómo estás?" and there's a trained completion for that sentence: "Estoy bien, ¿y tú?", the inference often returns exactly the same (which is good), but sometimes it adds non-encoded words: "Estoy bien, ¿y tú? CuÃ©ntame algo de ti", adding "Ã©" instead of "é".

Sometimes, it returns exactly the same sentence that was trained for, with no encoding issues.
I don't know if the inference is taking the non-encoded characters from my model or from somewhere else.

What should I do?
Should I encode the dataset in UTF-8?
Should I leave the dataset with UTF-8 and decode the bad encoded chars in the response?

The OpenAI docs for fine-tuning don't include anything about encoding.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue dealing with Portuguese strings.

Try to use `.encode("cp1252").decode()` after the string:

```
"CuÃ©ntame algo de ti".encode("cp1252").decode()
```

This should result in:

```
"Cuéntame algo de ti"
```

`cp1252` relates to the windows-1252 Western Europe codec. If that's not working, try another codec from here:
https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings

Comment: There's a problem when doing this to a string that contains both encoded and decoded characters, which is the case. So I think that happens because the model is merging different sentences, some well encoded and some wrong, so the problem is not solved with this. Maybe I trained the model incorrectly....
An example would be: "Estoy bien, ¿y tú? CuÃ©ntame algo de ti". With this sentence, I don't know what to do.

Comment: I tried "utf-8" rather than "cp1252" for French, and it seems great.